# Detect whether two controls on a Canvas collide

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, windows-store

My Windows Store project can move controls around on a `Canvas`, using `ManipulationDelta`. I want to create 'attachable' controls, where when you drag a control onto another control on the `Canvas`, rotate transforms applied on one of them will also be applied onto the other.

The simplest collision detection is to check whether the Rectangles of the two controls intersect, but since they can be rotated by any angle that's not possible.

How can this be done ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Intersect` method of `Windows.Foundation.Rect` class to determine if elements has common points.

Use my example:

```
private Rect DetectCollisions(FrameworkElement rect1, FrameworkElement rect2)
{
   var r1 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(rect1), Canvas.GetTop(rect1), rect1.ActualWidth, rect1.ActualHeight);
   var r2 = new Rect(Canvas.GetLeft(rect2), Canvas.GetTop(rect2), rect2.ActualWidth, rect2.ActualHeight);
   r1.Intersect(r2);
   return r1;
}
```

In this example 2 `Rect` objects was created from 2 incoming `FrameworkElement` objects.
Then we using `Intersect` method of first `Rect` to find out if rects has common points.
If so, method will store new intersection `Rect` to `r1` variable, instead of this it return `Rect.Empty` structure.

Comment: Does this method take rotations into account, when the `FrameworkElements` are at different angles with transforms applied on them ? I believe when we make a Rect with Left, Top, Width and Height only an axis-aligned rectangle is returned with the side angles at 90 degrees.

Comment: @AniruddhaVarma, look at [this](http://www.metanetsoftware.com/technique/tutorialA.html) article